# How do I create a binding (Emscripten) for a function that accepts a `std::function &&`?

Tags: javascript, c++, emscripten, embind

I have a function that takes a `std::function` as a parameter:

```cpp
class Foo {
    virtual void bar(std::function<void()> &&func) = 0;
};
```

I want to create a JS wrapper that implements Foo.

```cpp
struct FooWrapper : public wrapper<Foo> {
    EMSCRIPTEN_WRAPPER(FooWrapper);

    void bar(std::function<void()> &&func) override {
        call<void>("bar", std::move(func));
    }
};

EMSCRIPTEN_BINDINGS(Foo) {
        class_<Foo>("Foo")
                .smart_ptr<Foo>("Foo")
                .allow_subclass<FooWrapper, std::shared_ptr<FooWrapper>>("FooWraper", "FooWraperSharedPtr");
}
```

However, when I try to call `bar` from JavaScript (TypeScript), I get a `BindingError`.

```js
const foo = // Create Foo object
foo.bar(() => {
    // Do something
})
```

`BindingError: parameter 1 has unknown type NSt3__28functionIFvvEEE`

Does anyone know how to bind a `std::function` so that I can pass a JavaScript lambda function to it?

Comment: You cannot do it this way. Check the Web page https://emscripten.org/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/embind.html according to it, you can call JavaScript code from C++ if you declare a C++ interface class and implement it in Java Script, then use it in a call where the interface is an acceptable input. But you cannot represent `std::function` in Java Script as it isn't an interface.

Comment: I was hoping that Emscripten to convert a JavaScript lambda to/from a `std::function`. Apparently, that isn't the case.

Comment: No way for it to work this way. `std::function` is a template class included in the standart library. It's not a language feature.

Answer (score 0):

This actually is possible.

```cpp
EMSCRIPTEN_BINDINGS(FUNCTION_VOID) {
            class_<std::function<void()>>("Function_Void")
                    .constructor()
                    .function("opCall", &std::function<void()>::operator());
    }
```

The JavaScript can then execute a `std::function` by simply calling `opCall()`.